# Ruby gem timecop wrong delay between two dates after travel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, rspec-rails, timecop

I am using the helpful gem timecop (https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) for my tests with rspec and today an old unchanged test is breaking.

I might be mistaken in the way I am using it but using `pry` I printed the following:

```
Time.zone.now => Wed, 31 Mar 2021 15:09:45 CEST +02:00
```

```
6.months.from_now => Thu, 30 Sep 2021 15:09:56 CEST +02:00
```

```
Timecop.travel(6.months.from_now)
```

```
Time.zone.now => Thu, 30 Sep 2021 15:10:10 CEST +02:00
```

```
6.months.ago => Tue, 30 Mar 2021 15:10:15 CEST +02:00
```

Thank you in advance for any idea to understand or solve this.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Kudos for linking to a gem you have trouble with +1

Answer (score 1):

Ok it is my mistake, there is no 31st in September so it falls back to 30th and then 6 months ago is 30th of March.